# datejs TimeSpan and TimePeriod problems

Tags: javascript, timespan, datejs

I'm losing the plot with this one.  I've added date.js and time.js to my project.

I then having the following test code:

```
  1  var a = Date.today();
  2  var b = Date.today().next().friday();
  3  var ts = new TimeSpan(b - a);
  4  alert(ts.getDays());
```

I think everything is correct, yet i receive the following error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method at line 4!

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I managed to get it working. I was using an out of date copy of time.js. Thanks!

Comment: If geoffrey.mcgill's answer helped, please mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just ensure you are using the current Datejs release in SVN. http://www.datejs.com/svn/.

You can also just get the `.days` property.

**Example**

```
var a = Date.today();
var b = Date.today().next().friday();
var ts = new TimeSpan(b - a);

console.log(ts.days);
```

**EDIT**

Within the time.js package of Datejs, along with the `TimeSpan` class, there is a `TimePeriod` class which further breaks the difference between two Dates down to include `.months` and `.years`.

Here's a full sample using a randomly generated `year` value. The two `console.log` values should be the same.

**Example**

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*12);

var a = Date.today();
var b = Date.today().add(random).years();
var tp = new TimePeriod(a, b);

console.log('random', random);
console.log('years', tp.years);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how to find difference in years ? ( eg. 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2014 = 2 )

Comment: Get the two year values and subtract them?

Comment: yes, got it already, just was stack with TimeSpan and thought there is a similar method for years

Comment: I added a `TimePeriod` sample, which will accurately calculate the `year` and `month` difference between two `Date` objects.